# Highpass/lowpass a set of {N,2} data, where first column is the time?

Tags: filtering

How can I highpass/lowpass a set of data, where the sample rate is not fixed, but is the first column of data, ie when data = {{t1,x1},{t2,x2},...{tN,xN}}?

Comment: There are many ways you might do this e.g. interpolate to obtain evenly spaced data first.  However, one would need to know more about you data before recommending a way forward.

Answer (score 1):

One can do it by using a **TimeSeries** object:

```
t = Accumulate[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100]]; (* generate random times *)
y = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, Length[t]];   (* generate random values *)
ts = TimeSeries[y, {t}];     (* generate timeseries object *)
ts2 = LowpassFilter[ts, 0.6];    (* perform a lowpass filter *)
ListPlot[{ts, ts2}, Joined -> True]   (* show both series *)
```

giving:

[image: timeseries comparison]